# Event Sourcing using NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing

I'm moving from pure DDD paradigm to CQRS. My current concern is with Event Sourcing and, more specifically, organizing Event Store. I've read tons of blogs posts but still can't understand some things. So correct me if I'm wrong.

Each event basically consists of:
- Event date/time
- type of Event (we can figure out type of AggregateRoot from this as well)
- AggregateRoot id (Guid)
- AggregateRoot version (to maintain the order of updates)
- Event data (some serialized class with data necessary to make update)

Now, if my Event data consists of simple value types (ints, strings, enums, etc.) then it's easy. But what if I have to pass another AggregateRoot? I can't serialize the whole AR as a part of Event data (think of all the data and lazy loading), basically I only need to store Id of that AR. But then, when I need to apply that event, I'd need to get that AR from database first. And it doesn't feel right to do so from my Domain Model (calling Repositories and working with AR Ids).

What's the best approach for this?

p.s. For a concrete example, let's assume there's a Model which consists of Task and User entities (both ARs). Task hold a reference to User responsible. But the responsible User can be changed.

**Update:**  I think I've found the source of my confusion. I believe event sourcing should be used only for building read model. And in this case passing Ids and raw data is ok. But the same events used on aggregates themselves. And this I cannot understand.

Comment: Take a look at this blog: http://abdullin.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In DDD an aggregate is a consistency/invariant boundary, so one may never depend on another to maintain its invariants. When we start using this design restriction we find very few situations where is necessary to store a full reference to the other, usually we store its id and (if necessary) version and a copy of the relevant attributes.

For  example, using the usual Order/LineItem and Product problem we would copy the Product's id and price in the LineItem,  instead of a full reference. This way prevents changes in the Product's price affect the Order/LineItem aggregate's invariants. If is necessary to update the LineItem price after Product price changes we need  to keep track of the PriceChanged event from used Products and  send a compensating command to the Order/LineItem. Usually this coordination/synchronization is handled by a saga.

Comment: Thanks! I think I've found the source of my confusion. I believe event sourcing should be used only for building read model. And in this case passing Ids and raw data is ok. But often I've seen the same technique used on aggregates themselves. And this I cannot understand.

Answer (score 0):

In Event Sourcing, the state of the aggregate is defined by Events, and nothing more. All domain model stuff (ala DDD) is there just to decide what domain events should be raised. Event should know nothing about your Domain, it should be simple DTO. In fact, it is perfectly OK to have Event Sourcing without DDD.

Comment: Sure, but I need DDD to handle all the complex business logic of real applications. And it's perfectly normal from DDD point of view to reference one AR from another. So I have to pass these references in my Events somehow and, eventually, store them.

Comment: yeah, it's ok to have various IDs in Domain Event. I was talking about Events having references to Domain classes (which just doesn't work).

Comment: Event should know a lot about domain. Events should encapsulate domain related facts that have happened. You should edit that a bit. It should be logic free.

Comment: Well as we all know bidirectional dependencies are bad. I'm pretty sure there is no exception here.

Comment: I believe bidirectional dependencies aren't exactly bad, they just often misused (and abused) and harder to implement. Anyway, in real life applications Events should contain references to Domain objects. Could be by Id (which I personally don't like). But it's impossible to "apply" that event from my Domain without going to Repository, which is ugly, especially since I've most probably queried it already to check some Business Rules. Maybe it's all just a matter of good infrastructure, or I just need to abandon some DDD knowledge and freedom to comply with CQRS.

Answer (score 0):

As i understand Event Sourcing, it is supposed to help people get rid of relational data models and ORM like NHibernate or Entity Framework, since each of them is a science on its own. Programmers could then simply focus on business logic. I saw here some relational schemas used for event stores, and they were simply ID, Version, Timestamp plus an NClob or NVarchar(max) column to store the event payload schema-less.